# Can't reach user data field, console says can't find user of undefined

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, undefined, render

I want to display logged use name at a left section on the page.
When i try to reach user displayName it says that it can't fin value of undefined. Can someone explain me why?

I have tried componentDidMount and some other methods, but it seems that something is wrong during render here

```
componentDidMount() {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            // If firebase has detect a user
            if (user) {
                this.props.setUser(user);
                this.props.history.push("/");
```

Here is the file

```js
class UserPanel extends React.Component {

    state = {
        user: null
    }


    componentDidMount(){
        this.setState({ user: this.props.currentUser })
    }



    dropdownOptions = () => [
        {
            key: "user",
            text: (
                <span>
                    Sign in as <strong>{this.state.user && this.state.user.displayName}</strong>
                </span>
            ),
            disabled: true
        },
        {
            key: "avatar", 
            text: <span>Change Avatar</span>
        },
        {
            key: "signout",
            // Set a signout Function to enable user to sign out of the chat
            text: <span onClick={event => this.handleSignOut(event)}>SignOut</span>
        }
    ];

    handleSignOut = (event) => {
        // You need to prevent form submission. Use event.preventDefault() in your handle submit function.
        event.preventDefault();
        firebase
            .auth()
            .signOut()
            .then(() => console.log("See you"));
    } 


    render(){

        console.log(this.props.currentUser);

// !this.state.currentUser ? <Spinner /> :
        return (
            <Grid style={{ background: '#4c3c4c' }}>
                <Grid.Column>
                    <Grid.Row style={{ padding: '1.2rem', margin: 0 }}>
                        <Header inverted floated='left' as='h2'>
                            <Icon name='code' />
                            <Header.Content>VirtualChat</Header.Content>
                        </Header>
                    </Grid.Row>


                    {/* User Dropdown Choices */}
                    <Header style={{ padding: "0.25em" }} as="h4" inverted>
                        <Dropdown 
                        trigger={<span>{this.state.user.displayName}</span>}
                        options={this.dropdownOptions()}
                        />
                    </Header>
                </Grid.Column>
            </Grid>
        )
    }
}


const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    currentUser: state.user.currentUser
})


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(UserPanel);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `this.state.user` is not a truthy-value until after `componentDidMount()`, which doesn't take affect until after the first render. During the initial-render, you are trying to access the value within an object that does not yet exist.

What you could do is implement a condition to check whether `this.state.user` is valid, otherwise display an empty string. The speed in which the component re-renders is very fast, so you wouldn't even notice the empty-string on first-render.

```
 <Header style={{ padding: "0.25em" }} as="h4" inverted>
    <Dropdown 
        trigger={<span>{this.state.user ? this.state.user.displayName : ""}</span>}
        options={this.dropdownOptions()}
    />
 </Header>
```

Comment: I had tried that before but it always do the false case and just launch the page without display the data. Even with console.log it can't display user data